# identifier 'DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH.CREATE_CHANGE_SET' must be declared

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe, oracle-cdc

I am using oracle 11g express edition and I am getting the below error when trying to create a change set.

```
Error report -

ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:

PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH.CREATE_CHANGE_SET' must be declared

ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:

PL/SQL: Statement ignored

06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

*Action:
```

I know CDC is desupported in later versions of oracle but I think it is supported here.

Can anyone help please/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does your user have 'execute' permissions on the dbms_cdc_publish package?

Comment: @pmdba I've tried to explicitly grant permission to the SYSTEM user with 'grant execute on DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH to SYSTEM;'But ORA-04042: procedure, function, package, or package body does not exist was the response.

Comment: Aside from the _correct_ answer supplied by @pmdba, why would you try granting privileges to SYSTEM?  If anything you should be granting it to some application related user, not to system management users created by oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Express Edition, which does not include Change Data Capture functionality.

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC101